# Spring Data JPA: Use xml files for entity mapping

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I had set up as simple spring data jpa program with hibernate. But now i want to remove the Annotations in my entity classes and use a xml file instead.

Does spring data provides any help for this or do i have to make this configuration on the hibernate site?

Comment: Hopefully this is for a school project, or you need to familiarize yourself with the syntax because you need to upgrade to annotation driven mapping -  No sane person would use XML based mapping today, unless you are maintaining a legacy system (and then I would consider it technical debt, to be fixed ASAP).

Comment: Entity metadata can be specified in an `orm.xml` file. See the [JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) for details. An example file is available on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/resources/META-INF/orm.xml). The complete XML schema for the file is available [here](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd).

Comment: @manish: Thanks for the information. I will try it. :)

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek Why is it bad to use XML based mapping. You are right. I try to get familiar with spring data in general and I thought it would be the best solution to store the mapping in a seperate file to keep it clean. What are the disadvantages?

Comment: @stefan2342xx, in the context of JPA (not necessarily in general), annotations are a great way for documenting Java code inline. Anyone reading the code for a JPA entity class can easily understand the entity structure, including mapping to database tables and columns, any constraints, etc. On the other hand, storing the mapping externally in an XML file would require the reader to know that a class is a JPA entity (and not a regular POJO) and then have to find the XML mapping file to understand the entity structure. This is why it is preferable to use annotations with JPA entities.

Comment: @manish is right, the annotation means you have 'code' in one location instead of spreading it. If you have a 'secret' mapping file the next developer may easily overlook it and not understand why his code hehaves differently than expected. Personally I try to avoid configuration file all-together. In my projects  all configuration is code, except for the `-Dspring.profiles.active` system property which profile to use (prod/staging/dev)

Comment: Okay thanks. Sounds reasonable. I will try annotations instead.